# A special issue: RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal

Tags: python, pytorch

This error

```
"RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions."
```

happens when I train my deep learning model using

```
model_cls = model_cls.to(device)
```

to load my model to GPUs. Meanwhile, the device is

```
device(type = 'cuda', index =2)
```

And I have 6 GPUs according to

```
import torch
torch.cuda.device_count()
```

Although the use of `cuda:0` can temporarily solve this training problem, it does not cure the symptoms. I hope there is a cure for the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days for debugging, I have found I use the

`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = cfg.device.split(':')[-1]`

to point the special GPU. Thus, When I use

```
device = torch.device("cuda:{}".format(cfg.device.split(':')[-1]))
```

There will be a bug happening. All in all, the relationship between `os.environ` and `torch.device` needs to be attentioned.

Comment: And I use device = torch.device("cuda:0") which works.